# parse data from a list of dictionaries (from an API) into a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, json, pandas, dictionary, parsing

I am trying to parse a list of nested dictionaries into a Dataframe. I am able to flatten the dictionaries well, but in the end i only have one row of data.

here is the api connection:

```
limit = 500
devices = []

for page_num in range(2): 
    print('-----')
    offset = page_num * limit
    url = url
    print('requesting: ', url)
    
    response = requests.get(url, headers=header)
    data = response.json()
    devices.extend(data['Items'])
```

which returns len(devices)=1000 (expected).
the following code should take the list of dictionaries and turn it into a dictionary:

```
res={}
for d in devices: 
    res.update(d)
    
print(str(res))
```

however it only returns one result. dictionary is correct, but when i normalize this it has the columns needed but only 1 row of data. Where am i losing the data?

here is a sample of the data, and the list 'devices' is specifically from the Items key:

```
{'ServiceCallId': '6a432bb8-a8f0-4048-8548-ac34e4ab32e5',
 'Offset': 500,
 'Limit': 500,
 'TotalResultCount': 1096255,
 'Items': [{'AlternativeDeviceNames': None,
   'AssociatedCompanies': None,
   'BrandName': 'CD Horizon',
   'CatalogNumbers': [{'CatalogNumber': 'X0709272',
     'IsTransactional': None,
     'IsLabeled': None,
     'CatalogCompanyName': '[DUPLICATE] Medtronic Sofamor Danek, Inc.'}],
   'CombinationProduct': False,
   'CommercialDistributionEndDate': '2018-10-08T00:00:00',
   'Company': {'CompanyId': 1975,
    'CompanyName': '[DUPLICATE] Medtronic Sofamor Danek, Inc.',
    'CompanyNameShort': '',
```

Comment: Please provide a sample of the data you are attempting to parse.

Comment: I put a sample, hope this helps.